# Access Form Resolution Changes When Going to a Computer

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I designed a Microsoft Access program for work and on my computer the forma look great with no issues. When a couple of my coworkers open the program however, the form looks like the blown up at about 1.5x what is should be. All the widths, font sizes, etc. are the same it just looks zoomed in.

I have checked the monitor screen resolution and we have the same resolution and graphics cards. I also have the resize set to true on the form.

I don't know what else to do and I know this is annoying for my coworkers to work with. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Check *Settings, System, Screen, Scaling and Layout*, and then the percentage setting for: *Size of text, apps, and other elements*.

Comment: @Gustav I went into there and both computers are set at small for the percentage for text. I would like to note that Excel and Word don't have this issue just Access

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a good and a bad screenshot?